# How to change the color of the container box as pre the click in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I generated some containers using the for loop. I need to change the container color as per the click. The color should change according to the select and unselect in flutter.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate widget and use it in list like the following

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TapboxA extends StatefulWidget {
  const TapboxA({super.key});

  @override
  State<TapboxA> createState() => _TapboxAState();
}

class _TapboxAState extends State<TapboxA> {
  bool _active = false;

  void _handleTap() {
    setState(() {
      _active = !_active;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _handleTap,
      child: Container(
        width: 200.0,
        height: 200.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _active ? Colors.lightGreen[700] : Colors.grey[600],
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            _active ? 'Active' : 'Inactive',
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now in main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
           children: List.generate(5, (index) => TapboxA());
         }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```